# how to get access token and profile info when user login through Facebook in php

Tags: php, facebook

I implement login Facebook with php sdk. it works fine. I want to get access token and user profile info and then send them to my server and show the page with the Facebook info. How can I do that?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'my id',
'app_secret' => 'My secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/facebook/re.php',$permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

?>
```

Comment: @AdrianVeidt. could you explain more?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started

Comment: @AdrianVeidt. I use PHP, not js. I want to get it in server-side

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the callback function.
The callback URL that Facebook redirects the user to after login dialog is called /fb-callback.php.

you are named it as re.php.

```
   $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId({app-id}); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

Comment: I did it but get the error `Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token.`